# View() function in RStudio Server opens new tab but does not display data

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04, rstudio-server, google-cloud-compute-engine

I am running an Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS server on Google Cloud Compute Engine. I have downloaded RStudio Server onto my machine and kept getting this message:

> Warning message: R graphics engine version 15 is not supported by this
> version of RStudio.  The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer
> version of RStudio is installed.

So, I updated my RStudio version, and now for some reason the View function isn't working. It appears to open a tab in RStudio, but no data appears. Even with small datasets, it is not working.

Here is my sessionInfo:

> R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3 LAPACK:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
> LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8      [5] LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8
> LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
> [9] LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C
> LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] RMySQL_0.10.23 DBI_1.1.3
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_4.1.3
> tools_4.1.3

and here is my RStudio.version:

> $citation
>
> To cite RStudio in publications use:
>
> RStudio Team (2022). RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for
> R. RStudio, PBC, Boston,   MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.
>
> A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is
>
> @Manual{,
> title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
> author = {{RStudio Team}},
> organization = {RStudio, PBC},
> address = {Boston, MA},
> year = {2022},
> url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},   }
>
> $mode [1] "server"
>
> $version [1] ‘2022.7.1.554’
>
> $long_version [1] "2022.07.1+554"
>
> $release_name [1] "Spotted Wakerobin"
>
> Connected to your session in progress, last started 2022-Aug-19
> 18:52:27 UTC (2 hours ago)

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?